# How to compare string fields in the same table with ArcGIS 10

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.0, field-calculator, comparison

I don't know exactly if there is a tool for this or a maybe a python script could be more suitable.
I want to compare string elements from a field (POI_NAME) with another string element in another field (ROTULO). Find attached an screenshot.

My goal, AT LEAST, is to have a YES/NO matching, but It could be fantastic having a % of matching. Do anyone know anything about?

[image]

I tried something like this:

[image: Python code]

But it doesn't work.

After editing the code, to:

[image: New code]

We can see that it does not working well (BECAUSE IT HAS SPECIAL CHARS AND SPACES):

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you should compare your string in a case insensitive way. EDIT: I also add .strip() in case you have blank spaces in your string.

```
POI_name.lower().strip() == ROTULO.lower().strip()
```

Because Python is case sensitive and ROTULO is in capital letter

For further comparison, this is more a Python question. For instance, have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682367/good-python-modules-for-fuzzy-string-comparison) an SO, which uses [pylevenshtein](http://code.google.com/p/pylevenshtein/)

EDIT: I've tried this (from Wikibooks), and it worked nicely (the larger the value, the more different are the words

```
def lev(a, b):
    if not a: return len(b)
    if not b: return len(a)
    return min(lev(a[1:], b[1:])+(a[0] != b[0]), lev(a[1:], b)+1, lev(a, b[1:])+1)
```

Comment: I looked up for this issue you mentioned @radouxju, but still doesn't working.

Comment: @juasmilla "doesn't work" is far less helpful to people trying to help you than if you can say what is not working e.g. it gives an error, and what that precise error message is; or it updates the wrong rows; or it does not update all the rows; or it did not update any rows; etc; etc

Comment: Sorry you we're right. I forgot to edit my first question with this new income. Editing...just a sec.

Comment: I've tested my code and it worked with me. Is it possible that you have special characters or spaces ? Maybe you could try to compare the length of the field values (len(!POI_name!)-len(!ROTULO!) ) for debugging.

Comment: @radouxju as you said, I've found special chars and spaces... so this is not as simple as I thought.I'll have a look to the post you mentioned (pylevenshtein) but, unfortunatelly, I do not really know if could use its code in ArcGIS 10 field calculator.

Comment: Does this work? (Python as parser):  `"YES" if !POI_NAME!.lower().strip() == !ROTULO!.lower().strip() else "NO"`