# How to use "this" Levenshtein Python code into ArcGIS 10

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.0, field-calculator, comparison

I need some help with this:

First of all, I wanted to "Compare strings from two fields", and asking before at gis.stackexchange, in this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/95641/how-to-compare-string-fields-in-the-same-table-with-arcgis-10) someone help me with this topic, referring me to a Python code, but, unfortunately, from the deepest ignorance of this kind of issues, I wanted to know if it is possible to run this code within ArcGIS 10 (field calculator).

The code: [PyLevenshtein](http://code.google.com/p/pylevenshtein/) ,

Thanks in advance, and sorry if I wasted your time.

Answer (score 5):

First, you need to install it and it can be installed like any other Python module.

- Python setup.py install
- easy_install or pip install

But it is a Python C extension module (.so or .dll) and in Windows, there is no native compilers (as in Linux or Mac OS X).  You can download and install a version "ready" from Christopher Gohlke's [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#python-levenshtein)

After:

```
import Levenshtein
# absolute Levenshtein distance of two strings.
Levenshtein.distance('GIS StackExchange','StackExchange')
4
# similarity of two strings.
Levenshtein.ratio('GIS StackExchange','StackExchange')
0.8666666666666667
etc.
```

You can also use the standard [difflib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html) module ([Good Python modules for fuzzy string comparison?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682367/good-python-modules-for-fuzzy-string-comparison))

```
import difflib
difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, 'GIS StackExchange','StackExchange').ratio()
0.8666666666666667
```

and others.